# Div float on two sides with a vertical line separating them

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create two div elements floating side by side in the middle of the screen horizontally and vertically. But they are not getting displayed accurately.
here's the visual

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yhrz7.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXQg1.png)

Here's my HTML

```
<div id="config">
    <button class="echo-test-button" id="connect" ng-click="connect()">
        Connect
    </button>
    <button class="echo-test-button" id="disconnect" ng-click="disconnect()">
        Disconnect
    </button>
    <strong> Message</strong>

    <input type="text" ng-model="message" maxlength="40" placeholder="Enter Message Here" ng-disabled="isConnected"/>
    <button class="echo-test-button" id="sendMessage" ng-click="sendMessage(message)" ng-disabled="isConnected">
        Send
    </button>
</div>
<div id="log">
    <strong>Log</strong>
    <div id="consoleLog">
    </div>
    <button class="echo-test-button" id="clear" ng-click="clearLog()">
        Clear
    </button>
</div>
```

CSS File

```
#cofig{
  float: left;
}

#log{
  float: left;
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  width: 350px;
  border-left: solid 1px #cccccc;
}
```

Comment: `cofig != config`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a width on your `#log` div but not on your `#cofig` div.  This is going to mean that your `#cofig` div is going to take up 100% of the width.

Try making each of your divs have a width of 50%, or slightly less if you have margins/padding.

Answer (score 0):

Try with flex, get the two elements, delete that css, and put this:

```css
.contenedor{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrapper:nowrap;
}

.config{
  background-color:red;
}

.log{
  background-color:blue;
}

.config, .log{
  padding:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
<div class="config">
  lorem ipsum
  </div>
  <div class="log">
    lorem ipsum
  </div>
</div>
```

And from that, do whatever you want.

Hope it works for you!